# Did the gtk-integration of LibreOffice improve with 3.4?

Tags: gtk, libreoffice

In these release notes (http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/3.4#GUI) it reads that the gtk-integration should be improved. Does it look completely native now?

Comment: Questions like "does it look completely native" are a bit likely to cause problems in the answers - so I've voted for this to be closed (unless you want me to improve the question for you?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Before and after image .

[image]

Also Look at this bug:
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32186

Comment: also apparently it works better with Unity. I believe it looks better and more integrated. If only slightly